# Under what conditions is a rotation also a linear function.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

In a metric vector space a rotation is defined as an isometry which maps the origin onto itself. It is well-known that a rotation is a linear function in an inner product space. It is also known that this also holds in a normed vector space (Mazur & Ulam). Charzynski proved in 1953 that is also true in a finite dimensional F-normed vector space.
Is it true in a more general F-normed vector space?